# Expect PECL for PHP 7

Tags: php, expect, php7

I just upgraded to PHP 7.0.3, but there is no support for [expect](https://pecl.php.net/package/expect). Does anyone know if is it possible to bypass the installation issue? It says:

```
root@portal:/home# pecl install expect-0.3.3.tgz 
pecl/expect requires PHP (version >= 4.0.0, version <= 5.99.99), installed version is 7.0.3-5+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
No valid packages found
install failed
```

I searched around the internet, but I did not find any package with this PHP version. It was working fine on the previous installed version, 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open bug on php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72072) asking for php7 support.

In order to provide such a support the following compile time errors need to be solved.

```
[  131s] + /usr/bin/make -j1
[  131s] /bin/sh /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/include -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/main -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3 -I/usr/include/php7 -I/usr/include/php7/main -I/usr/include/php7/TSRM -I/usr/include/php7/Zend -I/usr/include/php7/ext -I/usr/include/php7/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c -o expect.lo 
[  131s] libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/include -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/main -I/usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3 -I/usr/include/php7 -I/usr/include/php7/main -I/usr/include/php7/TSRM -I/usr/include/php7/Zend -I/usr/include/php7/ext -I/usr/include/php7/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/expect.o
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c: In function 'OnSetExpectTimeout':
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:95: warning: passing argument 1 of 'atoi' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c: In function 'OnSetExpectMatchMax':
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:107: warning: passing argument 1 of 'atoi' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c: In function 'OnSetExpectLogUser':
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:120: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strncasecmp' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:121: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strncasecmp' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:122: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strncasecmp' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:123: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strncasecmp' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c: In function 'OnSetExpectLogFile':
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:142: error: 'new_value_length' undeclared (first use in this function)
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:142: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:142: error: for each function it appears in.)
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:143: warning: passing argument 1 of '_php_stream_open_wrapper_ex' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c: In function 'zif_expect_popen':
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:257: error: incompatible types in assignment
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c: In function 'zif_expect_expectl':
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:281: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zend_fetch_resource2_ex' from incompatible pointer type
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:283: error: wrong type argument to unary exclamation mark
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:298:74: error: macro "zend_hash_get_current_data" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:298: error: 'zend_hash_get_current_data' undeclared (first use in this function)
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:301:63: error: macro "zend_hash_get_current_key" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 3
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:301: error: 'zend_hash_get_current_key' undeclared (first use in this function)
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:313: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zend_hash_index_find' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:313: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_index_find'
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:323: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:326: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zend_hash_index_find' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:326: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_index_find'
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:334: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zend_hash_index_find' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:334: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_index_find'
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:367: error: too many arguments to function 'add_index_string'
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:380: error: too many arguments to function 'add_next_index_string'
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:388: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_index_find'
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:389: warning: passing argument 1 of 'zend_hash_index_find' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[  131s] /usr/src/packages/BUILD/expect-0.3.3/expect.c:389: error: too many arguments to function 'zend_hash_index_find'
[  131s] make: *** [expect.lo] Error 1
```